# Подскажите sql запрос на копирование дополнительных полей DLE

Tags: sql, dle

подскажите как скоприровать значение из доп полей в коментарии DLE.

Нужно и тблицы dle_post скоприровать значения доп.полей     xfields

```
INSERT INTO `dle_post` (`id`, `autor`,
 (id новости,  ....||review1|значение1||review2|значение2||review3|значение3|.....
```

в таблицу каометарии dle_comments

```
INSERT INTO `dle_comments` (`id`....
(1, id новости, 1, '', '', '', 'значение1', '', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); 
(2, id новости, 1, '', '', '', 'значение2', '', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
(3, id новости, 1, '', '', '', 'значение3', '', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Спасибо

Comment: Выложите: DDL (CREATE TABLE) обеих таблиц, пример данных (INSERT INTO, по 3-5 записей), желаемый результат на именно этих данных.

Comment: Пример таблиц
  [1]: https://yadi.sk/d/S__IUTmMqTabIw

Comment: Выложить - это вставить в текст вопроса. А ссылки на внешние ресурсы, к тому же способные в любой момент помереть - это ниачём...